# DNS Help with sub sub domain names

Tags: domain-name-system, email, subdomain, mx-record

I am not sure I even did this right, but I am trying to setup some sub domains with email services. So I want to have an email address like something@sub.domain.com. My problem is getting put in right. I am not sure I did.

```
$ORIGIN phxscouting.com.
$TTL 3600
@ IN SOA ns1.softlayer.com. root.phxscouting.com. (
                       2010012204        ; Serial
                       3600              ; Refresh
                       300               ; Retry
                       604800            ; Expire
                       3600)             ; Minimum

@                      3600     IN NS    ns1.softlayer.com.
@                      3600     IN NS    ns2.softlayer.com.

227.phxscouting.com    3600     IN MX 20 ALT1.ASPMX.L.GOOGLE.COM.
227.phxscouting.com    3600     IN MX 30 ALT2.ASPMX.L.GOOGLE.COM.
227.phxscouting.com    3600     IN MX 10 ASPMX.L.GOOGLE.COM.
227.phxscouting.com    3600     IN MX 40 ASPMX2.GOOGLEMAIL.COM.
227.phxscouting.com    3600     IN MX 50 ASPMX3.GOOGLEMAIL.COM.
820.phxscouting.com    3600     IN MX 20 ALT1.ASPMX.L.GOOGLE.COM.
820.phxscouting.com    3600     IN MX 30 ALT2.ASPMX.L.GOOGLE.COM.
820.phxscouting.com    3600     IN MX 10 ASPMX.L.GOOGLE.COM.
820.phxscouting.com    3600     IN MX 40 ASPMX2.GOOGLEMAIL.COM.
820.phxscouting.com    3600     IN MX 50 ASPMX3.GOOGLEMAIL.COM.
827.phxscouting.com    3600     IN MX 20 ALT1.ASPMX.L.GOOGLE.COM.
827.phxscouting.com    3600     IN MX 30 ALT2.ASPMX.L.GOOGLE.COM.
827.phxscouting.com    3600     IN MX 10 ASPMX.L.GOOGLE.COM.
827.phxscouting.com    3600     IN MX 40 ASPMX2.GOOGLEMAIL.COM.
827.phxscouting.com    3600     IN MX 50 ASPMX3.GOOGLEMAIL.COM.
@                      3600     IN MX 20 ALT1.ASPMX.L.GOOGLE.COM.
@                      3600     IN MX 30 ALT2.ASPMX.L.GOOGLE.COM.
@                      3600     IN MX 10 ASPMX.L.GOOGLE.COM.
@                      3600     IN MX 40 ASPMX2.GOOGLEMAIL.COM.
@                      3600     IN MX 50 ASPMX3.GOOGLEMAIL.COM.

calander.227.phxscouting.com 3600     IN CNAME ghs.google.com.
calander.820.phxscouting.com 3600     IN CNAME ghs.google.com.
calendar               3600     IN CNAME ghs.google.com.
calendar.827.phxscouting.com 3600     IN CNAME ghs.google.com.
docs                   3600     IN CNAME ghs.google.com.
googleffffffffbd82c380 3600     IN CNAME google.com.
mail                   3600     IN CNAME ghs.google.com.
mail.227.phxscouting.com 3600     IN CNAME ghs.google.com.
mail.820.phxscouting.com 3600     IN CNAME ghs.google.com.
mail.827.phxscouting.com 3600     IN CNAME ghs.google.com.
short                  3600     IN CNAME ghs.google.com.
sites                  3600     IN CNAME ghs.google.com.
227                    3600     IN A     74.86.80.229
820                    3600     IN A     74.86.80.229
827                    3600     IN A     74.86.80.229
@                      3600     IN A     74.86.80.229
cubby                  3600     IN A     74.86.80.229
ftp                    3600     IN A     74.86.55.26
webmail                3600     IN A     74.86.80.229
www                    3600     IN A     74.86.80.229
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You specified "$ORIGIN phxscouting.com." at the top of the file, which means the name server will append "phxscouting.com." to the end of every entry following in the file that isn't terminated with a period.

So as you currently have it specified, the first MX line

> 227.phxscouting.com    3600     IN MX 20 ALT1.ASPMX.L.GOOGLE.COM.

will actually refer to a mail address of "something@227.phxscouting.com.phxscouting.com".  You instead should specify the line as

> 227    3600     IN MX 20 ALT1.ASPMX.L.GOOGLE.COM.

or

> 227.phxscouting.com.    3600     IN MX 20 ALT1.ASPMX.L.GOOGLE.COM.

which would match "something@227.phxscouting.com".

Answer (score 0):

It's not necessary to specify each time a TTL of 3600, it's already your default value because your default entry : $TTL 3600